# How to change position of Angular Material placeholder in angular8?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-input

I have `angular8` project in which i have `angular material`. I am using `mat-autocomplete` for input autocomplete. Here is the code of my html

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width dummy-input-field" floatLabel="never">
    <input matInput class="custom-input" placeholder="State"  [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
        <img class="example-option-img" aria-hidden [src]="state.flag" height="25">
        <span>{{state.name}}</span> |
        <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</form>
```

Here is my complete [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwkutg) to demonstrate my issue. There is a placeholder inside input that says 'State'. I want to position this `placeholder` in the vertical middle of input like normal input boxes of `Html`.

How can i change the position of `angular material` input placeholder's position ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

[stack blitz working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplet-demo)

fallow angular material initial [steps](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) and import the require dependencies

Hope this will helps

Comment: i customize `material autocomplete` so can you edit in my given `stackblitz` link? because in your working example you are using `angular-material autocomplete` but i customized it to my needs. So please edit in my example.

Comment: In your example also when i am trying to give border to `input` of `anglar-material` autocomplete so it seems like my example. When i am giving border to material input inside `mat-autocomplete` so placeholder/label seems at inappropriate position.